# Most Pythonic way to provide function metadata at compile time?

Tags: python, plugins, metadata, python-decorators

I am building a very basic platform in the form of a Python 2.7 module. This module has a read-eval-print loop where entered user commands are mapped to function calls. Since I am trying to make it easy to build plugin modules for my platform, the function calls will be from my Main module to an arbitrary plugin module. I'd like a plugin builder to be able to specify the command that he wants to trigger his function, so I've been looking for a Pythonic way to remotely enter a mapping in the command->function dict in the Main module from the plugin module.

I've looked at several things:

1. **Method name parsing:** the Main module would import the plugin module
   and scan it for method names that match a certain format. For
   example, it might add the download_file_command(file) method to its
   dict as "download file" -> download_file_command. However, getting a
   concise, easy-to-type command name (say, "dl") requires that the
   function's name also be short, which isn't good for code
   readability. It also requires the plugin developer to conform to a
   precise naming format.
2. **Cross-module decorators:** decorators would let
   the plugin developer name his function whatever he wants and simply
   add something like @Main.register("dl"), but they would necessarily
   require that I both modify another module's namespace and keep
   global state in the Main module. I understand this is very bad.
3. **Same-module decorators:** using the same logic as above, I could add a
   decorator that adds the function's name to some command name->function mapping local to the
   plugin module and retrieve the mapping to the Main module with an
   API call. This requires that certain methods always be present or
   inherited though, and - if my understanding of decorators is correct - the function will only register itself the first time it is run and will unnecessarily re-register itself every subsequent time
   thereafter.

Thus, what I really need is a Pythonic way to annotate a function with the command name that should trigger it, and that way can't be the function's name. I need to be able to extract the command name->function mapping when I import the module, and any less work on the plugin developer's side is a big plus.

Thanks for the help, and my apologies if there are any flaws in my Python understanding; I'm relatively new to the language.

Comment: Just checking you realise this, but decorators (and function definitions) execute at runtime, the only thing Python does at compile time is compile your code.

Comment: Nothing wrong at all with method 2. Have them do something like `import plugin` and do `@plugin.register('my_method_name')\ndef somefunc_meeting_an_api_spec():...`

Comment: You might want to have a look on how [plac](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plac) does that.

Comment: Wouldn't something like ``cmd.Cmd`` in conjunction with ``readline`` tab expansion support negate the need to worry about short names.

Comment: @sotapme: Thanks, this is almost exactly the sort of thing I've been trying to build! Unfortunately, it seems that Cmd registers methods by inheriting them, so I think that means I would need to do multiple inheritance on the Main module dynamically at runtime to use different plugins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

User-defined functions can have arbitrary attributes. So you could specify that plug-in functions have an attribute with a certain name. For example:

```
def a():
  return 1

a.command_name = 'get_one'
```

Then, in your module you could build a mapping like this:

```
import inspect #from standard library

import plugin

mapping = {}

for v in plugin.__dict__.itervalues():
    if inspect.isfunction(v) and v.hasattr('command_name'):
        mapping[v.command_name] = v
```

To read about arbitrary attributes for user-defined functions see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

Comment: This is exactly the type of thing I was looking for!

Comment: I realize this question is a bit old, but see my related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192712/how-can-attributes-on-functions-survive-wrapping. Have you run into problems with wrapping using attributes stored on functions?

Answer (score 14):

Building or Standing on the first part of @ericstalbot's answer, you might find it convenient to use a decorator like the following.

```
################################################################################
import functools
def register(command_name):
    def wrapped(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        wrapped_f.__doc__ += "(command=%s)" % command_name
        wrapped_f.command_name = command_name
        return wrapped_f
    return wrapped
################################################################################
@register('cp')
def copy_all_the_files(*args, **kwargs):
    """Copy many files."""
    print "copy_all_the_files:", args, kwargs
################################################################################

print  "Command Name: ", copy_all_the_files.command_name
print  "Docstring   : ", copy_all_the_files.__doc__

copy_all_the_files("a", "b", keep=True)
```

Output when run:

```
Command Name:  cp
Docstring   :  Copy many files.(command=cp)
copy_all_the_files: ('a', 'b') {'keep': True}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts in a plugin system:

1. Discover plugins
2. Trigger some code execution in a plugin

The proposed solutions in your question address only the second part.

There many ways to implement both depending on your requirements e.g., to enable plugins, they could be specified in a configuration file for your application:

```
plugins = some_package.plugin_for_your_app
    another_plugin_module
    # ...
```

To implement loading of the plugin modules:

```
plugins = [importlib.import_module(name) for name in config.get("plugins")]
```

To get a dictionary: `command name -> function`:

```
commands = {name: func 
            for plugin in plugins
            for name, func in plugin.get_commands().items()}
```

Plugin author can use any method to implement `get_commands()` e.g., using prefixes or decorators — your main application shouldn't care as long as `get_commands()` returns the command dictionary for each plugin.

For example, `some_plugin.py` (full source):

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b

def get_commands():
    return {"add": f, "multiply": lambda x,y: x*y}
```

It defines two commands `add`, `multiply`.

Comment: Thanks you; I like the design explanation behind to this. This explanation suggests that a superclass that implements the get_commands() list might be a good idea, so the developers have to do as little work as possible.

Comment: @mieubrisse: no classes are required. I've added the complete plugin example.